# Most powerful test for discrete variable

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

> The discrete random variable X has the following probability distributions under $H_0$ and $H_1$
>
> $$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrrr}
> x&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
> \hline p(x)\;\mbox{under}\;H_0&0.63&0&0.09&0.08&0.07&0.01&0.02&0.03&0.05&0.02\\
> p(x)\;\mbox{under}\;H_1&0&0.42&0.12&0.05&0.09&0.01&0.04&0.08&0.12&0.07
> \end{array}$$
>
> A single observation is to be made on X. Identify the best (most powerful)
>   test of ﬁxed level (exactly) α = 0.10 for discriminating between
>   $H_0$ and $H_1$. [Hint: Consider all possible tests which have α = 0.10 and
>   compare their power. Remember, a test is speciﬁed by specifying its
>   critical region.]

Edit: I think I can calculate the power if I have the critical region for both hypotheses. But I don't know how to find the critical region when the probability distribution is discrete.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? I am struggling with this as well.

Comment: Nope! at least not that I remember